# How to do Import-Export to Excel functionality in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

In my asp.net web application there is a requirement where i have to import and export data to and from an excel. how can i do it?

Comment: Are you looking to export to Excel 2003, 2007, or 2010? The OleDb jet version varies for each version of Excel.

Comment: You have post 45 questions and you have not cost any up vote yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is code to export data in excel

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=excel" + ".xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    rptMain.DataBind();
    rptMain.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

and here is code to import Data from Excel

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
        DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
        DbCommand selectCommand = factory.CreateCommand();
        selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ColumnNames FROM [Sheet1$]";
        DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        selectCommand.Connection = connection;
        adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dtbl);

        if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
         .............
         .............
        }
```